# Difficult Series to analyse

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, limits

I have the following series,

$$ \sum_{t=N}^\infty F(t,N),$$

$$ F(t,N) = Max \, \{ \, \, \,1 - A(t) \, \,e^{-\frac{ N \,b}{ t} }\, ,   \, \, \, \, 0\, \, \, \} $$

where $A(t)$ cannot grow faster than polynomially with $N$. How should $A(t)$ behave in order this sum to be finite and to grow at least exponentially with $N$?

In case the first question has no answer, can then the same series, with the following function (with the square power of $N/t$ in place of $N/t$) be finite and grow exponentially with N? If yes, for which functions $A(t)$?

$$ F(t,N) = Max \, \{ \, \, \,1 - A(t) \, \,e^{-(\frac{ N }{ t} )^2 \,b}\, ,   \, \, \, \, 0\, \, \, \} $$

Comment: Have you experimented with any particular $A(t)$?

Comment: If 0<A(t)<1 for every t, then the series is divergent. 

I am trying to understand what happens when A(t) is a constant > 1. In this case the function becomes negative for t large enough and the Max is 0. Thus the series converge, but thus the quantity grows exponentially with N?